# RabbitMQ queue with messages but when i try to getMessages by the interfaces receve the message "queue is empty"

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, queue, message, rabbitmq-exchange

RabbitMQ queue with messages but when i try to getMessages by the interfaces receve the message "queue is empty"

I have a queue that has 200 messages, at the RabbitMQ inteface the number os messages apear normaly

but when i try to consume thoose messages i receve de message "the queue is empty" (when i do by the rabbitMq Interface or by some API)

ia deleted the queue and re-created (it works)

but i don't understand what happens and how avoid this.

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Welcome!  You'll probably need to provide more details before people can help you. When you say you deleted and re-created and it works: Does the error return?  If not, it's possible you just had a typo in name of queue or something like that :)  If the problem is still happening, you should try to come up with a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you clarify where in the interface you see your message count? Is it in the "ready" count, or the unacked count? If it is in the unacked count, it would explain the behavior you describe